# Any way to iterate a tuple in swift?

Tags: swift

I am curious how to do a for loop with a tuple in swift.

I know that to access each member you can use dot notation using the index number

```
var tupleList = ("A",2.9,3,8,5,6,7,8,9)

for each in tupleList {
    println(each)
}
```

//Error: Type does not conform to protocol sequence

Comment: Why use a tuple instead of an array if you want to iterate over it?

Comment: It seems, for me at least, that fixed-sized arrays imported from a C header becomes tuples. This, however, could be a side-effect of not having arrays with a fixed size.

Comment: Let arrays are fixed immutable now. I think that was back on beta 3

Comment: The problem still is that fixed C arrays can be mutable.

Comment: @drewag Perhaps you want to go through a tuple's elements and normalize them.  You could use an array, but your code is much cleaner expecting a fixed-size tuple and specific element labels.  You could also write a normalization `func` that's specialized to your fixed-size tuple, but in the spirit of keeping your code DRY, you'd really like a generalized solution.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, you can!

```
func iterate<C,R>(t:C, block:(String,Any)->R) {
    let mirror = reflect(t)
    for i in 0..<mirror.count {
        block(mirror[i].0, mirror[i].1.value)
    }
}
```

And voila!

```
let tuple = ((false, true), 42, 42.195, "42.195km")
iterate(tuple) { println("\($0) => \($1)") }
iterate(tuple.0){ println("\($0) => \($1)")}
iterate(tuple.0.0) { println("\($0) => \($1)")} // no-op
```

Note the last one is not a tuple so nothing happens (though it is a 1-tuple or "Single" which content can be accessed `.0`, `reflect(it).count` is 0).

What's interesting is that `iterate()` can iterate even other types of collection.

```
iterate([0,1])              { println("\($0) => \($1)") }
iterate(["zero":0,"one":1]) { println("\($0) => \($1)") }
```

And that collection includes `class` and `struct`!

```
struct Point { var x = 0.0, y = 0.0 }
class  Rect  { var tl = Point(), br = Point() }
iterate(Point()) { println("\($0) => \($1)") }
iterate(Rect())  { println("\($0) => \($1)") }
```

Caveat: the value passed as the 2nd argument of the block is type `Any`.  You have to cast it back to the values with original type.

Comment: In swift 2 reflect(t) is replaced by Mirror(reflecting: t) but this documented as a playground/debugging feature only.

Comment: Jafar, I don't think it's implied by [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html) that mirrors are to be used by playgrounds and debugger _only_. What is specifically stated in the documentation is "Mirrors are used by playgrounds and the debugger."

Comment: Doing this works just fine in Swift 4 [with a bit of change in syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50424747/4711811)

Answer (score 24):

You can using reflection **Swift 5**

Try this in a Playground:

```
let tuple = (1, 2, "3")
let tupleMirror = Mirror(reflecting: tuple)
let tupleElements = tupleMirror.children.map({ $0.value })
tupleElements
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Consider adding *print(tupleElements)* for non-playground

Answer (score 12):

Swift does not currently support iterating over tuples.

The biggest reasons are:

1. There is no way at runtime to determine the number of elements in a tuple
2. There is no way to access an element at a specific index except for the compile time accessors like `tupleList.0`. You would really want a subscript `tupleList[0]` but that is not provided to us

Frankly, I can't see a reason that you would use a tuple instead of an Array if you want to iterate over it.

It doesn't make sense to iterate over a tuple because:

1. Tuples always have a fixed length and each element has a fixed type
2. You can name each tuple member with a name you can use to access it later

Arrays are well made to iterate over:

1. Arbitrary length
2. Can store multiple types using a common superclass or AnyObject
3. Can be declared as a literal in a similar fashion to tuples: `var list = ["A",2.9,3,8,5,6,7,8,9]`

Comment: I was thinking to iterate over a tuple that came out of a function.

Comment: you can name each member of the type in result of a function and access each element by name. A tuple is meant to be a cheap struct that you don't have to predefine a type for. You can't iterate over the members of a struct either. (at least not until / if they add reflection to Swift)

Comment: You cannot substitute a tuple for an array if your members are not of the same type, for example.

Comment: I was also stuck with a same situation, suppose I have two sides "left" and "right". So I will prefer making a tuple like `let side = (left:"left", right:"right")` so that I can access them by name to make it error free. And say I have 10 category of  objects with left and right type in each category, so I want to iterate over each category. How can I? I won't use array since for some case I want to use things like `side.left`

Answer (score 9):

[@dankogai's excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299045/any-way-to-iterate-a-tuple-in-swift#24831640), updated for Swift 3.0:

```
func iterate<Tuple>(_ tuple: Tuple, body: (_ label: String?, _ value: Any) -> Void) {
    for child in Mirror(reflecting: tuple).children {
        body(child.label, child.value)
    }
}
```

Usage remains identical to @dankogai's examples *(beyond Swift 2's `println()`→`print()` rename)*.

<sub>*Note that the label is now of type `String?` when it was formerly `String`, to match the type change from Swift 1's `MirrorType.subscript(…).0` to Swift 3's `Mirror.Child.label`.  However, for labelless tuples the `label` arg comes back as `".0"`, `".1"`, `".2"`, etc.— it's only `nil` for some other types.*</sub>

<sub>*Also, I took the liberty of renaming types & args to better match [Swift 3's solidified naming standards](https://swift.org/blog/swift-3-api-design/), and changing the closure return type to `Void`.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

### Details

- Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500), Swift 5.1

### Base Solution

```
struct Tuple<T> {
    let original: T
    private let array: [Mirror.Child]
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.original = value
        array = Array(Mirror(reflecting: original).children)
    }
    func forEach(closure: (Mirror.Child) -> Void) { array.forEach { closure($0) } }
    func getOnlyValues<T: Any>() -> [T] { array.compactMap { $0.value as? T } }
    func getAllValues() -> [Any] { array.compactMap { $0.value } }
}
```

### Usage on base solution

```
let num: Int? = 3
let str: String? = nil
let x = (1, "stew", str, 5.4, 2, num)

let tuple = Tuple(x)
tuple.forEach { print("\($0)") }

print("\(tuple.getAllValues())")            // [1, "stew", nil, 5.4, 2, Optional(3)]
print("\(tuple.getOnlyValues() as [Int])")  // [1, 2, 3]
```

### More sugar

```
func valuesFrom<V>(tuple: V) -> [Any] { return Tuple(tuple).getAllValues() }
func onlyValuesFrom<T,V>(tuple: V) -> [T] { return Tuple(tuple).getOnlyValues() as [T] }

print(valuesFrom(tuple: x))                 // [1, "stew", nil, 5.4, 2, Optional(3)]
print(onlyValuesFrom(tuple: x) as [Int])    // [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score -2):

No, you can't. The reason is that tuple items are not all required to have the same type, so you would not be able to know what type `each` should have.

Comment: That's as valid an arbitrary rationale as any I've heard at least :)  To completely buy it, however, would mean you couldn't iterate an NSArray :)

Comment: `Any` and `AnyObject` can be used to represent anything. That is what is used in `NSArray` or any other translations of `id` from Objective-C

Comment: Except function types, for some reason: "Any can represent an instance of any type at all, apart from function types." They should fix that.

Comment: @jasamer I disagree.  `Any` can represent any _data type_, which is logically distinct in OO languages like Swift.  Function refs are a different beast in OO— they're meant to be called directly or bound to statically (compile-time), not passed around in collections or transformed dynamically (which would require runtime interpretation).  That said, many plausible “Any-function” use-cases can be solved in Swift using generics.