# Convert an String to an array of int8

Tags: string, swift

I have an C struct (old library, blah blah blah) which contains an C string, now I need to convert CFString and Swift strings into this c string. Something like

```
struct Product{
   char name[50];
   char code[20];
}
```

So I'm trying to assign it as

```
productName.getCString(&myVarOfStructProduct.name, maxLength: 50, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

but the compiler is giving me the following error: cannot convert type (int8, int8, int8....) to [CChar].

Comment: It's funny because I just had the [opposite problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455773/converting-a-c-char-array-to-a-string).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
withUnsafeMutablePointer(&myVarOfStructProduct.name) {
    strlcpy(UnsafeMutablePointer($0), productName, UInt(sizeofValue(myVarOfStructProduct.name)))
}
```

Inside the block, `$0` is a (mutable) pointer to the tuple. This pointer is
converted to an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>` as expected by the
[BSD library function `strlcpy()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strlcpy.3.html).

It also uses the fact that the Swift string `productName` is automatically
to `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`
as explained in [String value to UnsafePointer<UInt8> function parameter behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063569/string-value-to-unsafepointeruint8-function-parameter-behavior). As mentioned in the comments in that
thread, this is done by creating a temporary `UInt8` array (or sequence?).
So *alternatively* you could enumerate the UTF-8 bytes explicitly and put them 
into the destination:

```
withUnsafeMutablePointer(&myVarOfStructProduct.name) {
    tuplePtr -> Void in
    var uint8Ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(tuplePtr)
    let size = sizeofValue(myVarOfStructProduct.name)
    var idx = 0
    if size == 0 { return } // C array has zero length.
    for u in productName.utf8 {
        if idx == size - 1 { break }
        uint8Ptr[idx++] = u
    }
    uint8Ptr[idx] = 0 // NUL-terminate the C string in the array.
}
```

Yet another possible solution (with an intermediate `NSData` object):

```
withUnsafeMutablePointer(&myVarOfStructProduct.name) {
    tuplePtr -> Void in
    let tmp = productName + String(UnicodeScalar(0)) // Add NUL-termination
    let data = tmp.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!
    data.getBytes(tuplePtr, length: sizeofValue(myVarOfStructProduct.name))
}
```

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &myVarOfStructProduct.name) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: Int8.self, capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: myVarOfStructProduct.name)) {
        _ = strlcpy($0, productName, MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: myVarOfStructProduct.name))
    }
}
```