# Use a Char array from Swift in C

Tags: c, swift

Currently I have three files

main.swift

```
var dog = Dog()

dog.age = 12
dog.name = "H" // This is the non workable code
```

CTester.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Dog {
    int age;
    char name[10];
} Dog;
```

and C Test-Bridging-Header

```
#import "CTester.c"
```

I am trying to use the C struct in Swift, however, the Char array shows up as an array of 10 Int8 in Swift. How can I take a Swift string and assign it to the char array?

Comment: C arrays are imported to Swift as *tuples*, which makes them inconvenient to use. Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461904/convert-an-string-to-an-array-of-int8 ?

Comment: Btw, you usually would import a h-file, not a c-file.

Comment: Thanks Martin that helps me understand why its doing Tuples, also thats a great link! I may be able to use the info in there to figure out how to do what I want to do. Yes I know I should use an H file as good practice but this is such a small test that it doesn't make since.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you can write some extension for your `Dog` like this:

**Swift 2**

```
extension Dog {
    var Name: String {
        mutating get {
            return withUnsafePointer(&self.name) {namePtr in
                let charPtr = UnsafePointer<CChar>(namePtr)
                //Sorry, this code may crash here...
                return String(CString: charPtr, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            }
        }
        set {
            withUnsafeMutablePointer(&self.name) {namePtr in
                let charPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>(namePtr)
                let size = sizeofValue(self.name)
                strncpy(charPtr, newValue, size - 1)
                charPtr[size - 1] = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**(Tested with Xcode 8 beta 4)

```
extension Dog {
    var Name: String {
        mutating get {
            return withUnsafePointer(&self.name) {namePtr in
                let charPtr = UnsafePointer<CChar>(namePtr)
                //The result may contain the Unicode replacement character ("\u{FFFD}")
                return String(cString: charPtr)
            }
        }
        set {
            withUnsafeMutablePointer(&self.name) {namePtr in
                let charPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>(namePtr)
                let size = sizeofValue(self.name)
                strncpy(charPtr, newValue, size - 1)
                charPtr[size - 1] = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Seeing [the linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461904/convert-an-string-to-an-array-of-int8) in Martin R's comment, there may be some room to improve...
(Especially using `strlcpy` reduces your code size with better safety. Please check it.)

But anyway, it works as:

```
dog.Name = "H"
print(dog.Name) //->H
```

---

I have found that getter of `Name` may crash your app...
"It works" in a restriction that you store only ASCII characters.

Comment: The getter does not seem to work for me. It prints instead the address of the String and the Type like so: (0x00000001003b2914, Unicode (UTF-8))

Comment: @StephenKac, sorry, but I cannot reproduce the same result. Don't you have any part of my code misspelled? I have checked my code both in OS X project and iOS project with Xcode 7.3.1 and works fine in both projects. I may be missing something, so I tried many things but I couldn't get anything like `Unicode (UTF-8)`.

Comment: @StephenKac, OK, I will append Swift 3 version of my code.

Comment: @MartinR, thanks. I think my code works well about NUL-terminating manually. But your suggestion seems to be quite better.

Comment: It works when looking at it through the lldb Debugger but if you try to print it to the screen it does does not print a single character.

Comment: That's another "I cannot" reproduce, and in this case, I assume we use the same version of Xcode, so, how do you "print it to the screen" ? Show your code.

Comment: Oops, sorry it was my fault. I capitalized Dog. My Bad.