# convert a single c char to string in swift

Tags: string, swift, char, interop

I am trying to user MailCore2 (Objective C) in my Swift project.

At the moment I try to retrieve all IMAP Folders from a server (so far that works) and to split the paths by the delimiter.

```
INBOX.Sent
INBOX.Drafts
```

to

```
INBOX
 > Sent
 > Drafts
```

The Class `MCOIMAPFolder` has the property `delimiter` which is a `char`. If I try to print this or use it to split the paths:

```
print("\(folder.delimiter)\n")
var components = folder.path.componentsSeparatedByString(String.init(folder.delimiter))
for component in components {
    print("\(component)\n")
}
```

it will print

```
46
INBOX.Sent
```

The closest I could find here was [Converting a C char array to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455773/converting-a-c-char-array-to-a-string) but this only seems to apply to `char[]` and not a single `char`.

So what am I missing?

Comment: The question you linked to doesn't have the [c] tag... Do you wonder why?

Comment: @Freenode-newbostonSebivor To be honest, I don't. :-/ Obviously I am blind for the obvious answer...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C, so it shouldn't contain the C tag.

Comment: @Freenode-newbostonSebivor: The question is about interoperability between C and Swift. I don't know what the common policy is, but I have seen many questions with both tags in such a situation.

Comment: @MartinR This question is about interoperability between whichever ABI supports Swift, C, C++ and potentially a whole host of other programming languages... The question and answer for all of those languages is the same, so they should all be tagged too, right?

Comment: @MartinR You can see a similar argument was raged in [the related question that emKay linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455773/converting-a-c-char-array-to-a-string)... How did that turn out?

Comment: @Freenode-newbostonSebivor,MartinR I don't think we have to start this discussion again here. I removed the [c] tag as the issue targets Swift and not C. Thank you both for helping!

Comment: @emKay Perhaps [interop] might be a good tag to add?

Comment: @Freenode-newbostonSebivor True!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C type `char` is mapped to Swift as `CChar`, which is an alias for `Int8`. You can create a Swift string from a single C character with

```
let delim = String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(bitPattern: folder.delimiter)))
```

This interprets the given `char` as a Unicode value in the range
`0 ... 255` and converts it to a `String`.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! To my defense, this is not very obvious, is it? ;-)