# UnsafeMutablePointer for array using in C library

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to implement C library into my iOS project. I'm using swift language.

I have a function where the input parameter - where output values are stored - is ar usual C double array:

```
double ar[6];
///...
 err = c_lib_func(ar);
```

If I initialize inside swift like `var ar: [Double]` xCode says I have to use

`UnsafeMutablePointer`. But inside the docs I haven't found how to initialize n-lenght array for `UnsafeMutablePointer`. I just can do something like this:
`var ar : UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>`. But I can understand how to initialize it as 6-length array. Please, help me.

If I'm using

```
ar = [Double]
err = c_lib_func(ar);
```

the xCode shows to me this error:

> /Users/admin/Documents/projects/myApp/myApp/file.swift:46:46: Cannot
>   convert value of type '[Double]' to expected argument type
>   'UnsafeMutablePointer'

Comment: With `var ar: [Double]` you should be able to call `c_lib_func(ar)`.

Comment: @jtbandes , no. xCode show the error about using UnsafeMutablePointer

Comment: Please show your code and the error: [ask]

Comment: Someone wants to close this question? lol

Comment: Does using `&ar` to reference the underlying `UnsafeMutablePointer` work when `ar` is of type `[Double]`?

Comment: C arrays are imported to Swift as tuples, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455773/converting-a-c-char-array-to-a-string for a similar issue.

Comment: @Robert , can you write a sample of the code you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, `[Double]` is an array of double values which is not what you are after. If you want to initialize an UnsafeMutablePointer you can just use:

```
var ar = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.alloc(6)
```

Use ar.dealloc(6) to release the memory again.

Comment: Is it important to use `dealloc` inside swift?

Comment: Yes and it's also important that the value matches the value passed to alloc().