# Get Data from UUID in Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3, uuid

I have the following code written in Objective C that I am trying to get working in Swift 3. Some of the functions equivalents do not appear to be available in Swift 3. Here is the code is the code in Objective C

```
NSUUID *vendorIdentifier = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
uuid_t uuid;
[vendorIdentifier getUUIDBytes:uuid];
NSData *vendorData = [NSData dataWithBytes:uuid length:16];
```

and my current effort in Swift 3 which compiles and runs but is not giving the correct answer.

```
let uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
let uuidData = uuid?.data(using: .utf8)
let uuidBytes = uuidData?.withUnsafeBytes { UnsafePointer<UInt8>($0) }
let vendorData : NSData  = NSData.init(bytes: uuidBytes, length: 16)
let hashData = NSMutableData()
hashData.append(vendorData as Data)
```

Comment: could you add the results what you expect and what you get from the swift code?

Comment: I'm trying to. I don't do much in Objective C.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `uuid` property of `UUID` is a C array with is imported to Swift
as a tuple. Using the fact that Swift preserves the memory layout
of imported C structures, you can pass a pointer to the tuple
to the `Data(bytes:, count:)` constructor:

```
if let vendorIdentifier = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor {
    var uuid = vendorIdentifier.uuid
    let data = withUnsafePointer(to: &uuid) {
        Data(bytes: $0, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: uuid))
    }

    // ...
}
```

As of **Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10)** your don't need to make a mutable
copy first:

```
if let vendorIdentifier = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor {
    let data = withUnsafePointer(to: vendorIdentifier.uuid) {
        Data(bytes: $0, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vendorIdentifier.uuid))
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to make `&uuid.0` to `&uuid`?

Comment: With the copy-in/copy-out semantics of Swift inout parameters, Swift may prepare a region which can contain only one byte and pass the address of the region if you use `&uuid.0`. In most cases, `&uuid.0` would work, but it's not safe enough.

Answer (score 10):

This extension I made seems to work great without using reflection, nor pointers. It depends on the fact that UUID in Swift is represented as a tuple of 16 `UInt8`s which can simply be unwrapped like so:

```
extension UUID{
    public func asUInt8Array() -> [UInt8]{
        let (u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6,u7,u8,u9,u10,u11,u12,u13,u14,u15,u16) = self.uuid
        return [u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6,u7,u8,u9,u10,u11,u12,u13,u14,u15,u16]
    }
    public func asData() -> Data{
        return Data(self.asUInt8Array())
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it.  Should be the accepted answer as it doesn't involve any pointer ugliness.  On a side note, works as variables too:

`extension UUID{
    internal var bytes : [UInt8] {
        let (u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6,u7,u8,u9,u10,u11,u12,u13,u14,u15,u16) = self.uuid
        return [u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6,u7,u8,u9,u10,u11,u12,u13,u14,u15,u16]
    }

    internal var data : Data { Data(bytes) }
}
`

Answer (score 8):

To translate a `UUID` to `Data` in Swift 4.2, I used this:

```
let uuid = UUID()
withUnsafeBytes(of: uuid.uuid, { Data($0) })
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's one possible way. Note that `identifierForVendor` returns `UUID` in Swift 3. `UUID` has a `uuid` property which gives you a `uuid_t`. `uuid_t` is a tuple of 16 `UInt8` values.

So the trick is converting the tuple of bytes into an array of bytes. Then it's trivial to create the `Data` from the array.

```
if let vendorIdentifier = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor {
    let uuid = vendorIdentifier.uuid // gives a uuid_t
    let uuidBytes = Mirror(reflecting: uuid).children.map({$0.1 as! UInt8}) // converts the tuple into an array
    let vendorData = Data(bytes: uuidBytes)
}
```

If anyone knows a better way to convert a tuple of `UInt8` into an array of `UInt8`, please speak up.

Comment: I had to add bytes: let vendorData = Data(bytes: uuidBytes)

Comment: @Andrew In the playground I didn't need the `bytes:` parameter name.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2 Extension**

```
public extension UUID {

    var data: Data {
        return withUnsafeBytes(of: self.uuid, { Data($0) })
    }

}
```