# A function to convert a C char array to a String

Tags: arrays, tuples, interop, swift3

The [`statfs`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/statfs.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/statfs) struct in C has these `char` array members:

```
char f_mntonname[MNAMELEN];    /* directory on which mounted */
char f_mntfromname[MNAMELEN];  /* mounted file system */
```

The Swift type for these arrays in the `Darwin.sys.mount` module is a tuple with 90 elements:

```
public var f_mntonname: (Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8,
                         ...
                         Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8)
```

Another question about [Converting a C char array to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455773/converting-a-c-char-array-to-a-string/27456220#27456220) has an answer with code that I use twice in this example:

```
import Darwin.sys.mount
var vols: UnsafeMutablePointer<statfs>?
let count = getmntinfo(&vols, 0)    
if let volsarray = vols, count > 0 {
    for i in 0 ..< count {
        var vol = volsarray[Int(i)]
        let mntOnName = withUnsafePointer(to: &vol.f_mntonname) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self,
                                 capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vol.f_mntonname)) {
                String(cString: $0)
            }
        }
        let mntFromName = withUnsafePointer(to: &vol.f_mntfromname) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self,
                                 capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vol.f_mntfromname)) {
                String(cString: $0)
            }
        }
        print("on \(mntOnName)  from \(mntFromName)")
    }
}
```

To avoid repeating the code twice, I refactored the conversion code into the function below, but passing `&vol.f_mntonname` to it won't compile, and I can't see a way to fix the problem by using a different type for the first argument.

```
func charArrayToString(_ array: UnsafePointer<Int8>, capacity: Int) -> String {
    return array.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: capacity) {
        String(cString: $0)
    }
}

var a = (Int8(65), Int8(66), Int8(67))
print(charArrayToString(&a, capacity: 3)) // doesn't compile
```

The compiler complains about call to `charArrayToString`:
    Cannot convert value of type '`(Int8, Int8, Int8)`' to expected argument type '`Int8`'

It also complains when I pass `a` instead of `&a`:
    Cannot convert value of type '`(Int8, Int8, Int8)`' to expected argument type '`UnsafePointer<Int8>`'

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass a pointer to a tuple as a point to a `Int8`. Instead you need to pass a pointer to the first element of the tuple. For example define the function:

```
func charPointerToString(_ pointer: UnsafePointer<Int8>) -> String
{
   return String(cString: UnsafeRawPointer(pointer).assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self))
}
```

(This function is adapted from and example in Apple's [UnsafeRawPointer Migration](https://swift.org/migration-guide/se-0107-migrate.html)). Use this in your code to shorten your two `let`'s passing a pointer to the first tuple element:

```
let mntOnName = charPointerToString(&vol.f_mntonname.0)
let mntFromName = charPointerToString(&vol.f_mntfromname.0)
```

However, despite that following the code in Apple's document it seems a bit overkill, you can also just:

```
let mntOnName = String(cString: &vol.f_mntonname.0)
let mntFromName = String(cString: &vol.f_mntfromname.0)
```

*(All code tested using Xcode 8.2.1.)*

HTH