# Swift | Get pointer of c char array inside struct

Tags: c, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to convert some old ObjC code to Swift, I haven't done a lot with Swift regarding Pointers.

Original ObjC/C code:

```
unsigned char myId[6];
memcpy(myId, packet.header->m1, 6);
```

Original C Struct:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char m1[6];
    unsigned char m2[6];
} __attribute__((__packed__)) HeaderStruct;
```

My tried Swift code, not working:

```
var myId = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: 6)
var headerStruct: UnsafePointer<HeaderStruct> = packet!.header()
memcpy(&myId, headerStruct.pointee.m1, 6)
```

The error regarding `headerStruct.pointee.m1`

> Cannot convert value of type '(UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8,
>   UInt8)' to expected argument type 'UnsafeRawPointer?'

I assume I need the base address (headerStruct) and add the offset for the m1, but how do I do that?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27455773/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR you mean something like this: `memcpy(&myId, withUnsafePointer(to: packet?.header().pointee.m1){$0}, 6)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C array is imported to Swift as a tuple. But the memory layout is preserved, therefore you can obtain a pointer to the storage of the tuple and “bind” it to a pointer to `UInt8` values:

```
let myId = withUnsafeBytes(of: headerStruct.pointee.m1) {
    Array($0.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self))
}
```

Comment: I think it works (yay!, thanks for that), but wouldn't memcpy work too?

Comment: That would be `withUnsafePointer(to: headerStruct.pointee.m1) { memcpy(&myId, $0, 6) }`