# Why does this tuple -> String conversion trigger sporadic memory overlap exception

Tags: c, swift

I am working with some mixed C-Swift code that has a construction for converting a C-string in a struct to a Swift string like so:

```
struct MyCStruct {  // from the c header file
  char string[75];
}

extension MyCStruct {
  var swiftString: String {
    get { return String(cString: UnsafeRawPointer([self.string]).assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self)) }
  }
}
```

As of Swift 5.1, I started getting a sporadic memory overlap exception, possibly triggered by memory allocation elsewhere or a thread context switch.  I was able to fix it by changing the get to:

```
get { return withUnsafePointer(to: self.string) { ptr -> String in
            return String(cString: UnsafeRawPointer(ptr).assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self))
        } }
```

But, I am wondering is this just masking some deeper problem unrelated to the original construction?  Or, is the original construction faulty, and just lucky it never crashed before?

Comment: I’m currently trying to get the compiler to emit a warning for `UnsafeRawPointer([self.string])` :) https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/27695

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method relies on undefined behavior. Here

```
UnsafeRawPointer([self.string])
```

a temporary array is created, and the address of its element storage is passed to the `UnsafeRawPointer()` initializer. That memory address is only valid for the duration of of the `init` call, but must not be used when the initializer returns.

What you can do is to get a pointer to the `string` variable itself (which is mapped as a tuple to Swift) and rebind that (compare [Converting a C char array to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455773/converting-a-c-char-array-to-a-string)):

```
extension MyCStruct {
    var swiftString: String {
        withUnsafePointer(to: self.string) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: self.string)) {
                String(cString: $0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(It is assumed – as in your original code – that the C array of character is null-terminated.)

Comment: Thanks, are you saying that my alternative version is also relying on undefined behavior?

Comment: @user1055568: It is “wrong” in the sense that `ptr` is a pointer to a tuple, and you are telling Swift that it is a pointer to `CChar`. On the other hand it is (currently) “safe” in the sense that rebinding actually does nothing to the pointer or memory. Compare https://forums.swift.org/t/pointer-conversions-between-different-sockaddr-types/3827/2 in the Swift forum: *“... you're now making an untrue assertion about the memory type ... . A code verification tool--like a hypothetcial pointer sanitizer--could call you out on this.”*

Comment: Here is a better link: https://forums.swift.org/t/pointer-conversions-between-different-sockaddr-types/3799 – *“Your `withMemoryRebound` solution is correct.”*