# Swift: convert already allocated char array to char pointer

Tags: c, swift

I am attempting to interface an existing C library to Swift 5.0.1 code on iOS.  The C Header files have the following definitions:

```
char hostname[SFL_MAX_HOSTNAME_CHARS+1];
char os_release[SFL_MAX_OSRELEASE_CHARS+1];
```

```
int readHidCounters(HSP *sp, SFLHost_hid_counters *hid, char *hbuf, int hbufLen, char *rbuf, int rbufLen);
```

```
typedef struct _HSP {
    [Many other elements omitted for brevity]
    char hostname[SFL_MAX_HOSTNAME_CHARS+1];
    char os_release[SFL_MAX_OSRELEASE_CHARS+1];
  } HSP;
```

`readHidCounters` has an implementation (edited for brevity) like this:

```
int readHidCounters(HSP *sp, SFLHost_hid_counters *hid, char *hbuf, int hbufLen, char *rbuf, int rbufLen) {
    int gotData = NO;
    size_t len = hbufLen;
    if(sysctlbyname("kern.hostname", hbuf, &len, NULL, 0) != 0) {
      myLog(LOG_ERR, "sysctl(<kern.hostname>) failed : %s", strerror(errno));
    }
    else {
      gotData = YES;
      hid->hostname.str = hbuf;
      hid->hostname.len = strlen(hbuf);
    }
    // UUID
    memcpy(hid->uuid, sp->uuid, 16);

    [...]
}
```

I have created an HSP struct and attempting to call `readHidCounters` in Swift like this

```
var sp = HSP()
[...]        
readHidCounters(&sp,
                &hidElem.counterBlock.host_hid,
                &sp.hostname, // This is the error line
                SFL_MAX_HOSTNAME_CHARS,
                &sp.os_release,
                SFL_MAX_OSRELEASE_CHARS)
```

I am attempting to pass in `&sp.hostname` results in the compiler error `Cannot convert value of type '(Int8, Int8, Int8, [...], Int8)' to expected argument type 'Int8'`.  The problem is that hostname is a tuple of Int8's and I can't seem to get it properly converted to `char *`.  I have tried various incarnations of `UnsafeMutablePointer`, `withUnsafeMutablePointer` and can't see how to get `hostname` properly recognized.  Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

[Solved]

MartinR pretty much nailed it with his suggestion, but it did have a compiler error: `Overlapping accesses to 'sp.hostname', but modification requires exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable`.  Updated code that compiles is

```
        var myHostName = sp.hostname
        var myOsRelease = sp.os_release
        let _ = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &myHostName) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: Int8.self, capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: sp.hostname)) {
                hostNamePtr in
                withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &myOsRelease) {
                    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: Int8.self, capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: sp.os_release)) {
                        osReleasePtr in
                        readHidCounters(&sp,
                                        &hidElem.counterBlock.host_hid,
                                        hostNamePtr, SFL_MAX_HOSTNAME_CHARS,
                                        osReleasePtr, SFL_MAX_OSRELEASE_CHARS)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The API is unclear to me. If hostname and os_release are part of the HSP structure (which is passed as the first argument to the function) then why do you have to pass the these arrays as arguments to the function as well?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27455773/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR I have added the partial implementation of `readHidCounters`.  What you say is true, maybe the implementors did not want to couple so tightly to `sp`?

Comment: Perhaps, I am not familiar with that library. – I have suggested something, but I could only verify that it *compiles,* not that it works in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “problem” is that C arrays are imported to Swift as tuples, and there is no simple method to treat a tuple as a Swift array, or get a pointer to the element storage (because a tuple can be inhomogeneous).

Similarly as in [Converting a C char array to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455773/converting-a-c-char-array-to-a-string) one can use the fact that Swift preserves the memory layout of structures imported from C, and with some pointer juggling and rebinding you'll get

```
let result = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &sp.hostname) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: Int8.self, capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: sp.hostname)) {
        hostNamePtr in
        withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &sp.os_release) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: Int8.self, capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: sp.os_release)) {
                osReleasePtr in
                readHidCounters(&sp,
                                &hidElem.counterBlock.host_hid,
                                hostNamePtr, SFL_MAX_HOSTNAME_CHARS,
                                osReleasePtr, SFL_MAX_OSRELEASE_CHARS)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another “trick” is to define C helper functions which return the array addresses as a pointers, and use the

- [SE-0044 Import as member](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0044-import-as-member.md)

feature to make these helper functions available to Swift as computed properties. In the bridging header file you have to add

```
__attribute__((swift_name("getter:HSP.hostNamePtr(self:)")))
static inline char * _Nonnull hostNamePtr(HSP * _Nonnull hsp)
{
    return hsp->hostname;
}

__attribute__((swift_name("getter:HSP.osReleasePtr(self:)")))
static inline char * _Nonnull osReleasePtr(HSP * _Nonnull hsp)
{
    return hsp->os_release;
}
```

and then you can use these easily  from Swift:

```
var sp = HSP()

let result = readHidCounters(&sp,
                          &hidElem.counterBlock.host_hid,
                          sp.hostNamePtr, SFL_MAX_HOSTNAME_CHARS,
                          sp.osReleasePtr, SFL_MAX_OSRELEASE_CHARS)
```

Comment: your solution is in line with some of my attempts, but you got it.  I had to tweak it a bit for some minor compiler complaints (working code added to question).  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the & from the call, *sp.hostname* is already a pointer because it is an array, if it works you will have to remove the & from *&sp.os_release* too

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work.  Removing `&` gives the error `Cannot convert value of type '(Int8, Int8, [...], Int8)' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?'