# UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<AudioBuffer> Speech To Text. Dangling Buffer Pointer

Tags: ios, swift, pointers, buffer

I have been trying to implement Google's Speech to Text API in iOS and I cam across this piece of code in their AudioController file. This piece of code

```
    let buffers = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>(start:
                                                            &bufferList.mBuffers, count: Int(bufferList.mNumberBuffers))
    
    buffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1
    buffers[0].mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * 2
    buffers[0].mData = nil
```

gives me this error

```
Initialization of 'UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>' results in a dangling buffer pointer
```

I've tried the solutions over on this question [Warning: Initialization of 'UnsafeBufferPointer<T>' results in a dangling buffer pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60857760/warning-initialization-of-unsafebufferpointert-results-in-a-dangling-buffer), but the solutions don't work as intended.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the same `AudioController`. I have found the solution [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-use-withunsafemutablepointer-with-swift-5-2/35453/5)

Code can be updated like this:

```
let buffers = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &bufferList.mBuffers) {
    UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: $0, count: Int(bufferList.mNumberBuffers))
  }
  ...
  ...    
  // get the recorded samples
  status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &bufferList) {
      AudioUnitRender(AudioController.sharedInstance.remoteIOUnit!,
                               ioActionFlags,
                               inTimeStamp,
                               inBusNumber,
                               inNumberFrames,
                               $0)
  }
```

Works for me fine