# How to convert from C char buffer to String in Swift in XCode 14?

Tags: c, swift, string, xcode14

There's a ton of references to this question but none of them seem to work. I'm using Xcode 14.1. What am I doing wrong?

I have a C buffer in a struct:

```
struct MY_C_STRUCT
{
    char buff[256];   //Contains null-terminated C-string in UTF-8 encoding
};
```

and I have a Swift struct where I'm trying to set its variable from `MY_C_STRUCT::buff`:

```
class MyStruct : ObservableObject
{
    @Published public var Buff : String = ""

    func from_MY_C_STRUCT(mi : MY_C_STRUCT)
    {
         Buff = String(cString: mi.buff)
    }
}
```

That gives me on the `String(cString:)` line:

> No exact matches in call to initializer

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27455773/1187415

Comment: Further info at this blog: https://oleb.net/blog/2017/12/swift-imports-fixed-size-c-arrays-as-tuples/

Comment: @MartinR there are like 5 suggestions there. I tried all of them and all gave me errors.

Comment: What errors? The code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27456220/1187415 (with `record.name` replaced by `mi.buff`, of course) compiles without problems in my test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this blog](https://oleb.net/blog/2017/12/swift-imports-fixed-size-c-arrays-as-tuples/) explains, Swift imports fixed-sized C arrays as tuples!

One way to treat the tuple as a buffer is to use `withUnsafeBytes` to get a pointer to the memory and then pass that pointer to `String(cString:)`:

Replace:

```
Buff = String(cString: mi.buff)
```

with:

```
Buff = withUnsafeBytes(of: mi.buff) { (rawPtr) -> String in
    let ptr = rawPtr.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self)
    return String(cString: ptr)
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'mi' is a 'let' constant` for that

Comment: @c00000fd: Replace `&mi.buff` by `mi.buff`