# How to transfer a string from C to Swift in Swift 5.x

Tags: swift

It seems that in the latest version of Swift (I show 5.7.1), this no longer works

```
    public var description: String {
      return String(cString: UnsafeRawPointer([self.s]).assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self))
    }
```

In debug, I can confirm that s in `self.s` is populated, however, an empty string is returned for description. This used to work in Xcode a few versions back, so I am perplexed why it is different now. What am I missing?

[image: self.s]

Perhaps I need to allocate some size to the String?

Comment: It seems that `self.s` is a *tuple* (the Swift representation of a fixed size C array) so this might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27455773/1187415

Comment: @MartinR this is the solution, thank you so much for your help! I wonder if this means all `UnsafeRawPointer([self.s]).assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self)` and `UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: &self.s).assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self)` must be replaced with something like this.

Comment: Your code gives a compiler warning “Initialization of 'UnsafeRawPointer' results in a dangling pointer” which indicates that it invokes undefined behavior, and should be replaced.

Comment: It was always undefined behavior, but the compiler warning is relatively new. See “The compiler will now emit a warning when attempting to pass a temporary pointer argument produced from an array, string, or inout argument to a parameter which is known to escape it.” in https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md, and the linked https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/issues/4326.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR. If I just want the non-string version, is this right? `        let result = withUnsafePointer(to: self.s) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: $0)) {
                $0
            }
        }`

Comment: I don't think so. The pointer may not be valid (“dangling”) when it escapes the `withUnsafePointer` call.

Comment: This should do the trick: `var description: String { withUnsafeBytes(of: self.s) { String(bytes: $0, encoding: .utf8)! } }` I just used a force-unwrap for brevity.  You should do something more appropriate when the `String` initializer fails.