# Swift: how to count the number of elements in Tuple

Tags: swift, tuples

I was wondering if there is a **method or function in Swift which can count the number of elements in the tuple**.

Reason of question:

1. I have a tuple called "tople"
2. What I want to do is to load the elements into variables (by using for loop, where you actually need the number of elements)
3. And then use this in a function.

---

### Additional questions, can you use **tuples** to load variables into the function and/or to return them from a function?

```
var tople = (1,2,3)

func funkce (a:Int, b:Int, c: Int){

    println(a)
    println(b)
    println(c)
}


funkce(a,b,c)
```

Thanks and I do appreciate any helpful comment.

Comment: I meant is there a property or method to get the number of elements from tuple.

Comment: You need to use reflection: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24831640/1535436

Answer (score 11):

In Swift 3 you count the number of elements in a tuple like this:

```
let myTuple = (1,2,3,4)
let size = Mirror(reflecting: myTuple).children.count
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can load tuples into variables.

```
let (a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3)
```

To extract values from a tuple, you can use MirrorType. You can find more [here](http://nshipster.com/mirrortype/).

```
let tuple = (1, 2, 3)
let count = Mirror(reflecting: tuple).children.count // 3
```

Comment: Thank you man, this is exactly what I needed. I do appreciate. (btw. you have the same name as one of my friends, who does not actually like Apple, so when I saw your comment, I was like "WHAT")

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with recent swift like Swift 5.  `error: Cannot find 'reclect' in scope`