# Access NSString *const *Array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, objective-c, pointers

Still trying my best to learn swift and hit this problem with some old library code -

I have something like this -

```
static NSString *const fooStrings[] = {
  @"Foo"
}
```

Getting a value through this is rather easy in Objective C:

```
NSString *foo = fooStrings[0];
```

How do I get these in Swift though? I've tried casting `UnsafePointer<NSString>` and getting the string back with code similar to that above. I also tried `fooStrings.elements[0]` or trying dereferencing with `&fooStrings.elements[0]` or `(fooStrings as UnsafePointer).pointee[0]`, but every time, it complains about not being able to do this with an `NSString * strong`.

I'm obviously out of my depth here and am asking for help as I wasn't able to find an answer to what looks like a straightforward thing to do.

Comment: Just `fooStrings[0]`. `NSArray` is toll-free bridged to Swift `Array` and `NSString` is toll-free bridged to Swift `String`

Comment: @Paulw11 The OP has a C-style array, not an `NSArray`.

Comment: You can create obj-c function that returns NSString from that array by index and use that function from swift. That would probably be cleaner than messing with unsafe pointers in swift.

Comment: That or convert it to a literal `NSArray`. `static NSArray<NSString> *fooStrings = @[@"foo"]`

Comment: Is there a way to do this conversion in Swift? It's an older library's code that someone else has written and not something I can directly modify.

If I was to use an ObjC function to return it, it might be a better idea to just have everything done in ObjC (would prefer not to since I'm learning Swift).

Comment: It's imported in swift as tuple, so it will be `fooString.0`. Do you need iterate over that array or `fooString.0` will be enough?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any way to iterate a tuple in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299045/any-way-to-iterate-a-tuple-in-swift)